# JQuery Netflix style tooltips?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'd like to have a tooltip (preferably using a jquery library) that allows me to pop open a div (who's content I can customize with html - forms, links, images etc.) at the location of a mouseover.

I'd like the div to remained fixed at a location relative to the element that was hovered over (and automatically handle edge of browser cases).  Hopefully I'd be able to customize various parameters such as how long after the mouseover the tooltip appears, how long the tooltip remains visible after mouseout (and the ability to keep it open until it is explicitly closed via a close button on the tooltip popup).

A google search yielded a few options but none with all of my requirements (at least from what I've seen).  Recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is pretty easy to use and does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at [jTip](http://codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/) before, seems pretty flexible. You might prefer jTip or qTip based on features and default looks. Both are easy to get going.